# How do I call a base class method through a member function pointer?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, virtual, member

This is related to my thread *Member Function Pointers and Inheritance* on *allegro.cc* [here](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/616520).

See the thread on *allegro.cc* for code examples.

I'm trying to call a base class method through a member function pointer on a virtual method in my `WidgetBase` class. However it calls the virtual method instead of the base class one. I want to call the base class method through a function pointer, but according to other threads here on stack overflow this is not possible.

So, my question is, what alternatives are there? Lambdas have been suggested, but I'm not sure how to implement that, as I have little experience with C++11 or C++14. Ideas would be welcome.

It is possible to call the base class method if the calling object is actually an instance of the `Base` class but this causes problems because it involves making a copy of the object I want to call the method on, which defeats the purpose of calling it on the object to begin with.

I was hoping there was some magical cast I could use to implement this, but using static cast to cast to the base class makes a temporary copy of the object, which again, is not what I want.

I want to use this to implement a helper function in my `TextDecorator` class, which will call a pre-selected state setter function on several different objects contained in the `TextDecorator`. `TextDecorator` is derived from `WidgetDecoratorBase`, which is derived from `WidgetBase`, which is where the base class functions I want to call reside. This helper function will then be called in the overridden versions of the state setter functions in the `TextDecorator` class.

Basically, what I want in pseudo C++ code is this :

```
void TextDecorator::SetFlagState(bool state , void (WidgetBase::*StateSetter)(bool)) {
    if (basic_text_widget) {
       (basic_text_widget->WidgetBase::*StateSetter)(state);
    }
    (text_widget_layout->WidgetBase::->*StateSetter)(state);
    (this->WidgetDecoratorBase::->*StateSetter)(state);
}
```

That would then allow me to make my state setting calls in `TextDecorator` clear and concise, to be called like this :

```
void TextDecorator::SetEnabledState(bool state) {
    SetFlagState(state , SetEnabledState);
}
```

where `SetEnabledState` is one of the virtual state setting functions in my `WidgetBase` class.

Please keep suggestions limited to possible ways to implement this. There has to be a clean concise way to do this in C++.

Comment: You say "there has to be a clean precise way to do this", and you are mistaken.   You are essentially trying to work around the intended working of a language feature (that making a call through a pointer to member function calls the most derived version if it is virtual), in a function that hasn't been provided with the information needed to do what you intend.

Comment: @Peter - It is a clear oversight of C++ if there is no way to call a specific member function through a member function pointer. In most cases calling the derived function would be correct, but in this case it is not, and if C++ does not provide for that, then it has fallen short imho. I do have faith there is a clean concise way to do this, I just don't know what it is. It may not involve member function pointers, but I never said it had to be done that way. Someone suggested lambda functions, but I don't have enough experience with them to know how to do it that way. Hence the call for help.

Comment: Sorry, MarcD, not so.  A large part of the point of virtual functions is that they resolve to the version of the function corresponding to the ACTUAL object, not to an inherited version.   This is a fundamental underpinning of polymorphism.   It is your requirement that is flawed.

Comment: @Peter - If a language is unable to perform a basic function such as this then the flaw is in it, not in the requirement. What good is a member function pointer that can't point to a specific member function? The ability to choose between a derived version and a base version is what is lacking here.

Comment: That's my point.   You're describing this as a "basic function".   It is not.   The point of virtual functions and function pointers is that the choice of function called depends on the actual type of the object, not on what base classes it has.

Comment: A function pointer is pretty basic C code. The fact that it doesn't point to the function that I want it to is flawed. Period.

Comment: A member function pointer is not actually a pointer, in the sense that you are expecting from C.   Anyway, you are judging a C++ concept that you don't understand, and which C doesn't even support, because you expect it to work consistently with C.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125256/discussion-between-marcd-and-peter).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is a slight refactoring of your base class. Instead of:

```
class Base {

public:

     virtual void foo()
     {
          // The base implementation of foo().
     }
};
```

Replace it with:

```
class Base {

public:

     virtual void foo()
     {
          foo_base();
     }

     void foo_base()
     {
          // base class implementation of foo.
     }
};
```

The replacement code is 100% logically equivalent. But now, you can obtain a pointer to the `foo_base()` method, and invoke it directly without any particular difficulty.

Comment: I think this is probably the best way to refactor my code, but it means renaming a bunch of functions and reimplementing them, so it will have to wait for now. I just went and used direct qualification to the functions involved. Sad to see I can't do this with a MFP.

Comment: There's nothing to reimplement. It's nothing more than changing the name of an existing method and deleting its "virtual" keyword, then adding four lines of code. That's it.

Comment: Not true. I would have to rename all the existing virtual functions or reimplement them to call the base class helper function. I could leave the functions as is and remove virtual but then I would still have to change the widget implementations to use the new 'base' implementations. There is a whole library of widgets that use these functions. It's not as simple as adding four lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to call the base class method through a function pointer, but according to other threads here on stack overflow this is not possible.

As far as I know, you can't do that.
The pointer doesn't carry enough information with it.
Invoking a member function through a pointer to a member function is like doing a direct call.
I suspect there doesn't exist any mapping with things like `this->B::f()` (note that `(this->B::*ptr)()` is not a valid syntax).

> So, my question is, what alternatives are there? Lambdas have been suggested, but I'm not sure how to implement that

Of course, you can work around it easily with a lambda function.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

struct B {
    virtual void f() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

struct D: B {
    void f() override { std::cout << "D" << std::endl; }

    template<typename F>
    void g(F &&f) { std::forward<F>(f)(*this); }
};

int main() {
    D d;
    d.g([](auto &i){ i.B::f(); });
}
```

Instead of passing a pointer to a member function, you pass a delegate lambda that does the work under the hood.
The drawback of this approach is that it doesn't work out of the box if the virtual member function is a private one.

---

As requested in the comments, I'm adding more details.

Let's look over this:

```
template<typename F>
void g(F &&f) { std::forward<F>(f)(*this); }
```

In this case, `g` is a function template that accepts a callable object. The `&&` near to `f` are there because `f` is a forwarding reference and it can be used to bind either to an lvalue reference or to an rvalue reference.
I'd suggest to read [this](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) article by Meyers, when he also suggested the terms *universal reference* for the same thing.
The `std::forward` serves the purpose of forwarding the variable by preserving exactly its type. Note that a variable having type *rvalue reference to* would be an lvalue reference in the context of `g` otherwise.
In the article above mentioned this is explained with more details.

Now consider this line of code:

```
d.g([](auto &i){ i.B::f(); });
```

We are invoking `g` using a generic lambda as an argument.
It's not strictly necessary, we could have used this instead:

```
d.g([](D &i){ i.B::f(); });
```

Apart for the fact that the type is deduced, the idea is that we receive an instance of a class that derives from `B` and we call the implementation of `f` from `B` on that instance.
Who is demanded to give use such a reference?
Back to the previous snippet:

```
template<typename F>
void g(F &&f) { std::forward<F>(f)(*this); }
```

Nite that here we are invoking `f` (that is our lambda) using `*this` as an argument (it forms a reference to an object of type `D`).

That's all.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what that does? I'm not very familiar with lambas, or std::forward.

Comment: @MarcD Ok, let me add more details.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what's going on but it's getting clearer. I'm still not sure how that helps me call the specifically derived function I want. If I have to qualify the function by name that defeats what I am trying to achieve. I hate macros, but I think in this case a macro would be best, as it can simply and easily replace the function name whereas a member function pointer doesn't seem to be able to.